# How to use AWS CloudFormation templates with Simple System Management and ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I am trying to use AWS CloudFormation templates together with SSM and ElasticBeanstalk, but get the following error:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-dg6tmg2rmj-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [ssmParameter].

I basically need to retrieve values from SSM and use as environment variables on Amazon Linux.

I have already researched and read all the related material on AWS CloudFormation official material, but things are not clear on the use of these templates.

Here is my template's code:

```
Resources:
  ssmParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: "MySSMParameter"

option_settings:
  'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment':
     MY_ENV_VAR: {"Fn::GetAtt": "ssmParameter"}
```

This solution was already tested as explained in this [AWS blog post titled 'Integrating AWS CloudFormation with AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store'](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)

Nevertheless, now another error is shown:

> InvalidParameterValue: Unknown Parameter Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the error message: `Unknown Parameter Type`

The correct form is `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<TYPE>` where `TYPE` is the, ahem, type of the parameter :D

For example, to extract a String: `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>`